# Запустить shell команду в Scala

Tags: shell, scala, hadoop

Надо выполнить консольную команду для получения размера файла:

```
hadoop fs -du some/path
```

и сохранить результат в переменную.
Как это сделать в Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import scala.sys.process._

val result = "hadoop fs -du some/path" !!
```

[Документация](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/sys/process/index.html).